# Columns into array and then indexing multiple arrays in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to rearrange some data file by making every column into it's own array and then manipulating it. Later I will use the index of the column arrays to reorder the rows, but for now, I am really confused about the loop and how to get the index to work.

My current code is as follows:

```
import csv as csv
import sys as sys

freq = []
J_i = []
w_i = []
n_i = []
J_f = []
w_f = []
n_f = []

infile = open('Rearrange Column Test.txt')
sys.stdout = open('Rearrange Column TestNEW.txt', 'w')
for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
    newline = [line[i] for i in [20, 0, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10]]
    newline[2] = newline[2].split('=')[1]
    newline[4] = newline[4].split('=')[1]
    freq.append(float(newline[0]))
    J_i.append(float(newline[1]))
    w_i.append(float(newline[2]))
    n_i.append(float(newline[3]))
    J_f.append(float(newline[4]))
    w_f.append(float(newline[5]))
    n_f.append(float(newline[6]))
    for j in freq, J_i, w_i, n_i, J_f, w_f, and n_f:
        print freq[j], J_i[j], w_i[j], n_i[j], J_f[j], w_f[j], n_f[j]
        if J_f[j] == J_i[j]:
            if w_i[j] == 0.5 and w_f[j] == 0.5:
                Tline = "Q_{+}^{+}("
            elif w_i[j] == -0.5 and w_f[j] == 0.5:
                Tline = "Q_{-}^{+}("
            elif w_i[j] == -0.5 and w_f[j] == -0.5:
                Tline = "Q_{-}^{-}("
        elif J_f[j] - J_i[j] == 1:
            if w_i[j] == 0.5 and w_f[j] == 0.5:
                Tline = "R_{+}^{+}("
            elif w_i[j] == -0.5 and w_f[j] == 0.5:
                Tline = "R_{-}^{+}("
            elif w_i[j] == -0.5 and w_f[j] == -0.5:
                Tline = "R_{-}^{-}("
        elif J_f[j] - J_i[j] == -1:
            if w_i[j] == 0.5 and w_f[j] == 0.5:
                Tline = "P_{+}^{+}("
            elif w_i[j] == -0.5 and w_f[j] == 0.5:
                Tline = "P_{-}^{+}("
            elif w_i[j] == -0.5 and w_f[j] == -0.5:
                Tline = "P_{-}^{-}("
    print Tline, J_i[j], ")"
sys.stdout.close()
```

I am just really confused with the index that I can use. I want to make sure that I am printing the exact same position from each column array (5th value from freq and 5th value from J_i, etc), and also doing operations on the same index value in the J_i and J_f column arrays. Can someone please help me to get this loop to work correctly?

Example data:

```
0.5   0.6801  0.5 omi=-0.5  -1 --->   1.5 0.5 omf= 0.5 -1.0   0.3301 frq= -0.3501   0.6667       0.5974   0   0  1.00 frq=   3723.6699 xint=  1.0667
1.5   0.3301  0.5 omi= 0.5  -1 --->   0.5 0.5 omf=-0.5 -1.0   0.6801 frq=  0.3501   0.6667       0.7788   0   0  1.00 frq=   3724.3701 xint=  0.6667
0.5  -0.0044  0.5 omi= 0.5   1 --->   0.5 0.5 omf= 0.5 -1.0   0.0216 frq=  0.0260   1.3333       1.0034   0   0  1.00 frq=   3724.0460 xint=  1.3333
```

Example Desired Output:

```
3723.6699    0.5  -0.5  -1  1.5  0.5 -1.0   R_{-}^{+}(0.5)
3724.3701    1.5   0.5  -1  0.5 -0.5 -1.0   P_{+}^{-}(1.5)
3724.0460    0.5   0.5   1  0.5  0.5 -1.0   Q_{+}^{+}(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the same index for multiple arrays, use:

```
for j in xrange(len(freq)):
```

And then this should go through all the the lines assuming that your frequency array has the same number of entries as all of your other arrays.

Your code is also missing a condition for  "_{+}^{-}" in each branch which could cause mislabeling of transitions because the if statement will not correct the Tline entry and keep the value from the last run to use in the new line.

Also, for your if statements, it is better not to use == because floats will have rounding errors when storing a decimal number.

The following code should help clear things up:

```
import sys as sys
import struct
import decimal


#Small value for if statements
eps=1e-2

#Create empty sets to append with column values
freq = []
J_i = []
w_i = []
n_i = []
J_f = []
w_f = []
n_f = []
Tline = []

#Import data, split into columns you want, then assign column values to arrays
#3s = next three spaces are a string that I want to look at
#19x = skip the next 19 spaces in document
#Decimal used to keep last digit of frequency even if it is zero
#Used float to make numbers out of string. Can now do operations on numbers.
with open("path/to/file","r") as f:
    for line in f:
         (col0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6) = struct.unpack("3s19x4s2x2s8x3s9x4s5s65x10s14x",line.strip())
         freq.append(decimal.Decimal(col6))
         J_i.append(float(col0))
         w_i.append(float(col1))
         n_i.append(float(col2))
         J_f.append(float(col3))
         w_f.append(float(col4))
         n_f.append(float(col5))

#Define each line with the transition       
for j in xrange(len(freq)):
    if abs(J_f[j] - J_i[j]) < eps:
        if abs(w_i[j] - 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] - 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("Q_{+}^{+}(")
        elif abs(w_i[j] + 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] - 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("Q_{-}^{+}(")
        elif abs(w_i[j] - 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] + 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("Q_{+}^{-}(")
        elif abs(w_i[j] + 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] + 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("Q_{-}^{-}(")
    elif abs(J_f[j] - J_i[j] - 1) < eps:
        if abs(w_i[j] - 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] - 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("R_{+}^{+}(")
        elif abs(w_i[j] + 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] - 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("R_{-}^{+}(")
        elif abs(w_i[j] - 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] + 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("R_{+}^{-}(")
        elif abs(w_i[j] + 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] + 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("R_{-}^{-}(")
    elif abs(J_f[j] - J_i[j] + 1) < eps:
        if abs(w_i[j] - 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] - 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("P_{+}^{+}(")
        elif abs(w_i[j] + 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] - 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("P_{-}^{+}(")
        elif abs(w_i[j] - 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] + 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("P_{+}^{-}(")
        elif abs(w_i[j] + 0.5) < eps and abs(w_f[j] + 0.5) < eps:
            Tline.append("P_{-}^{-}(")

#Rearrange the Columns, then
#Write out new arrangement with specified widths to align columns
sys.stdout = open('path/to/file', 'w')
for i in xrange(len(freq)):
    print '{:>9}  {:>3}  {:>4}  {:>4}  {:>3}  {:>4}  {:>4}  {:>10}{:>3}{:>1}'.format(freq[i], J_i[i], w_i[i], n_i[i], J_f[i], w_f[i], n_f[i], Tline[i], J_i[i], ")")
sys.stdout.close()
```

Then you can use for statements and the indices of the column arrays to change the order of the rows. Good luck!